# Webcam flickering

Tags: webcam

My Webcam is flickering.
I tried to change settings in GUVCView and in v4l2ucp (see screenshot, you can see there grey and white stripes, they change all the time) but this does not help, both with power line frequency 60 Hz and 50 Hz.
The cam is AUKEY Webcam 1080P Full HD and I have ubuntu 18.04.
I must have artificial light because my office has no windows.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `uvcvideo` driver is the problem.
From

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Webcam/

I came to

https://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices

and there my webcam is **not** listed. With e. g. Logitech C920 which is listed there evertyhing is working.